# Form Builder - What to use it for and what not to use it for

Tags: dynamic-data, formbuilder, dynamic-forms

We are building a Form Builder (why reinvent the wheel and not use an existing one is not a discussion I want to have) for my company. Development is going well and I believe we have the right strategy for making it flexible enough and robust enough.

However, the problem lies in expectations. As project leader, it is my job to make sure expectations align with deliverable functionality, in fact project success depends on it, but I am having trouble defining what the form builder should be used for. I am concerned top management thinks of it as a one-size-fits-all solution, something I disagree with. I believe there are use cases for Form Builders and then there are use cases for explicit implementations, not all data should be stored in a dynamic form builder.

My question is: Is there a rule of thumb for determining what type of data should be implemented in a dynamic Form Builder and what should not? Or maybe not one but a set of rules.

For example, a purchase request might be a good fit for the form builder, but employee registration and attendance to company training sessions might not be since you'll most likely want to have that data readily available for querying and statistics.

Which types of forms should be implemented using dynamic form builders and which should have explicit static implementations in the database?

Answer (score 0):

For my experience Forms builders are useful for specific cases. When you want to create interfaces for experience users to facilitate the management of data. When designing applications that are concern about the user’s experience, the form builders are all most the times not useful.